# Using viewbag in view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my Controller I've created a viewbag attribute named OptionList in which I created one string with some options for a selectpicker I'd like to use in my view.

```
foreach(Uren_IssueType type in IssueType_List)
{
    optionList = optionList + "<option>" + type.TypeNaam + "</option>";
}
ViewBag.OptionList = optionList;
```

Because it's a dynamically created selectpicker (It's part of every row in a grid in which the rows can be added and removed dymanically) I want to add this optionlist to a string in which the selectpicker is created.

```
<td width=\"125\">
    <select class=\"form-control\" id=\"selectpicker\" name='selectpicker'>
         @ViewBag.OptionList
    </select>
</td>
```

But this code does work only the option are not displayed. It shows a empty dropdownlist. Can someone help me with how to create this selectpicker list from the viewbag string?

Comment: Why are you using a viewbag? Take a read of this: https://www.jamietech.com/2015/10/14/mvc-view-models-or-viewdata/

Comment: Why dont you use List of SelectListItem and store the list in ViewBag.???Then bind the ViewBag to dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render Html from a string use `Html.Raw`.

```
@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.OptionList)
```

But, the more Asp.Net MVC way of doing this would be [using DropdownList](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc) (or DropDownListFor) to render something from the model, rather than building up HTML in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the items from the viewbag.
Something like:

```
<td width=\"125\">
    <select class=\"form-control\" id=\"selectpicker\" name='selectpicker'>
    @foreach(var item in ViewBag.OptionList)
    {
        <option value="@item">@item</option>
    }         
    </select>
</td>
```

And the ViewBag should be created like:

```
List<string> items=new List<string>();
foreach(Uren_IssueType type in IssueType_List)
{
    items.Add(type.TypeNaam)   
}
ViewBag.OptionList = items;
```

Comment: I did this for the original row. But I'm using the string to be able to dynamically add new rows. And withing the string this won't work because when using the viewbag like this in the view gives me a syntax error.

But thnx for the help